# Javascript Function with parameters that span multiple lines

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, multiline

I want to use a function in javascript that has many parameters that likely have long names.  I want it to look something like this:

```
functionName( parameter1,
              parameter2,
              parameter3 );
```

so far I've tried doing the following to no avail:

```
functionName( parameter1, \
              parameter2, \
              parameter3 );
```

I understand that "\" is supposed to have things continue on to the next line.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried your code?

Comment: You obviously mixed up with multiline strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need any special character to span lines. Your original is fine:

```
functionName(parameter1,
             parameter2,
             parameter3) {}
```